# How to fix: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_2: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, keras, machine-learning-model

I have a question concerning time series data. My training dataset has the dimension (3183, 1, 6)

My model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape = (training_input_data.shape[1], training_input_data.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape = (training_input_data.shape[1], training_input_data.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='mse')
```

I get the following error at the second LSTM layer:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_2: expected
>   ndim=3, found ndim=2 But there is no ndim parameter.

Comment: Could you try `return_sequences=True` in the first layer and tell whether it worked or not?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first LSTM layer is returning something with shape `(batch_size, 100)`. If you want to iterate with a 2nd LSTM layer, you should probably add the option `return_sequences=True` in the first LSTM layer (which would then return an object of shape `(batch_size, training_input_data.shape[1], 100)`.

Note that passing `input_shape = (..)` in the 2nd LSTM is not mandatory, as the input shape of this layer is autoamtically computed based on the output shape of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set parameter return_sequences=True to stack LSTM layers.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(
    100,
    input_shape = (training_input_data.shape[1], training_input_data.shape[2]),
    return_sequences=True
))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape = (training_input_data.shape[1], training_input_data.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='mse')
```

See also [How to stack multiple lstm in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331510/how-to-stack-multiple-lstm-in-keras)