# The input shape and fitting in Keras LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am learning the LSTM model to fit the data set to the multi-class classification, which is eight genres of music, but unsure about the input shape in the Keras model.

I've followed the tutorials here:

1. [How to reshape input data for LSTM model](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/)
2. [Multi-Class Classification Tutorial with the Keras Deep Learning Library](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-classification-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library/)
3. [Sequence Classification with LSTM Recurrent Neural Networks in Python with Keras](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/)

My data is like this:

```
vector_1,vector_2,...vector_30,genre
  23.5     20.5          3      pop
   .
   .
   .
(7678)
```

I transformed my data shape into (7678,1,30), which is 7678 pieces of music, 1 timestep, and 30 vectors. For the music genre, I used `train_labels = pd.get_dummies(df['genre'])`

Here is my model:

```
# build a sequential model
model = Sequential()

# keras convention to use the (1,30) from the scaled_train

model.add(LSTM(32,input_shape=(1,30),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32,return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32))
# to avoid overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

# output layer
model.add(Dense(8,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Fitting the model

```
model.fit(scaled_train,train_labels,epochs=5,validation_data=(scaled_validation,valid_labels))
```

But when trying to fit the model, I got the error `ValueError: Shapes (None, 8) and (None, 1, 8) are incompatible`. Is there anything I did wrong in the code? Any help is highly appreciated.

The shape of my data

```
print(scaled_train.shape)
print(train_labels.shape)
print(scaled_validation.shape)
print(valid_labels.shape)
(7678, 1, 30)
(7678, 8)
(450, 30)
(450, 8)
```

**EDIT**

I've tried [How to stack multiple lstm in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331510/how-to-stack-multiple-lstm-in-keras)
But still, get the error `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_21 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 30]`

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, `return_sequences=True` will return a sequence (with a time step), That's why your output shape is `(None, 1, 8)`: the time step is maintained. It doesn't flatten automatically when it goes through the dense layer. Try:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32,input_shape=(1,30),return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(8,activation='softmax'))
```

I guess this doesn't happen if you uncomment the second LSTM layer?

Comment: Thank you, sir. When I uncomment the second LSTM layer, I got `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_7 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 30]`.

Comment: And I when I modify the return_sequences = False, I got `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_9 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 30]`

Comment: I am using LSTM because the vectors are extracted from audio, and `return_sequences=True` to not 'forget' the last vector.

Comment: It seems I need to transform my `scaled_validation` as well to 3D. Thank you, sir. @Nicolas